# Trouble with sending vanilla JS fetch to send post request on AJAX-enabled Login Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, fetch

I'm working on a project to use fetch to send a "post" request containing login information from a form, and I'm pretty sure I've written out the code properly, but I'm getting the error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" when I submit.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Here are the instructions:

1.Create a “Login” HTML form containing the form fields “username” and “password.”

2. Create a .js file and reference it in your HTML form document.
3. Make use of JavaScript fetch to send a POST request containing the form field values “username” and “password.” Send the request containing your username and password to https://ict4510.herokuapp.com/api/login. (ICT 4510 API Documentation (Links to an external site.)) If the request is successful, it will return an HTTP status code of 200 and the response will contain a user object.
   NOTE: You will be provided with a username and password. Email your instructor if you don't have credentials.
4. Save the user object found in the response to sessionStorage (HTML5 API).
5. Hide the form after a successful login, and display a Welcome message containing the user’s first name.

HTML:

```
<form class="form" id="myForm"> 

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    
    <input type = "text" name ="username" id="username">
    
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    
    <input type = "password" name ="password" id="password">
    
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<script src="js/fetchPost.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

const formData = new FormData(this);

fetch('https://ict4510.herokuapp.com/api/login', {

    method: 'post',

    body:  formData

}).then(function (response)  {

    return response.text();

}).then(function (text)  {

    console.log(text);

}).catch(function  (error)  {

    console.error(error);



})
});
```

Comment: Please show the relevant backend code; there's nothing obvious wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the backend code... I'm just writing the JS and html.  Is there a way that I could access that?

Comment: Well, where did you get `ict4510.herokuapp.com` from? Is there documentation available? How do you know to use `/api/login` and `inp_username` etc?

Comment: the server information was provided by my instructor and the form field names and ids are what we were instructed to use

Comment: Maybe you need to send a querystring instead: `body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()`

Comment: still getting the same error.  I'm loading the page through LiveServer from VSCode.  Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Server error 500 usually means that the server code that processes the request has crashed; I assume your instructor has done some basic testing first, so maybe there's something in the instructions you aren't implementing correctly? Can you add the relevant information to your question or link us to it?

Comment: Just made an edit to the post with the instructions and edited the labels, names, and ids of the form fields to reflect the project instructions.  Editing the form field info didn't make a difference when I attempted to submit the login info

Comment: I'm also still getting a 500 error; can you add the link to the API instructions?

Comment: Do you mean a link to the project instructions?  If so, I won't be able to post a direct link because it's part of a closed course.  But the instructions I posted are the same verbatim.

Comment: Oh, the "ICT 4510 API Documentation"?  Strangely that part of the instructions isn't actually a link and I haven't been able to find ICT 4510 API Documentation anywhere on our class website.

Comment: Your code is fine now, as far as I can see; it's still possible that bad credentials also cause an error 500.

Comment: I finally figured it out with the help of the Prof.  Here's the solution from the Prof:

Comment: The data needs to be stringified so it is sent properly to the server via fetch. Additionally, don't forget to add the headers attribute to fetch in order to expect a JSON response from the server. Thus, the response should be response.json() and no response.text(). This should be enough for you to get it to work:

const data = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(this)));

fetch('https://ict4510.herokuapp.com/api/login', {

method: 'POST',

body: data,
headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
}).then(function(response) {
return response.json();
})

Comment: Ok, so the server simply expected JSON.